# find -amin doesn't work if -name is excluded

Tags: linux

I am running GNU Linux 6.2 on x86_64 hardware.  I'm in a directory with 1237 files.  I want to list the files created in the last 36 hours and since I cannot get -atime to work, I use "-amin 2160":

```
$ find . -amin -2160 -name 'Ar*' -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 2318 Aug 30 04:04 ./Archivelog_backup_08302015040300.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 2317 Aug 30 10:03 ./Archivelog_backup_08302015100321.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 1920 Aug 30 16:21 ./Archivelog_backup_08302015160300.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 2318 Aug 30 22:04 ./Archivelog_backup_08302015220300.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 2318 Aug 31 04:03 ./Archivelog_backup_08312015040300.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 2318 Aug 31 10:04 ./Archivelog_backup_08312015100320.log
```

But since I don't care what the name is and I want to see ALL files touched in the last 2160 minutes, I type this command,

```
find . -amin -2160 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

but it lists all 1237 files in the directory PLUS THE 6 that meet the criterion.  Why?

Humbly,

Comment: If you used `ls -ld`, you'd also have avoided this.

Comment: Hi, Charles -- why does the absence of "-type f" cause the command to list all the files in the directory?

Comment: Because it's running `ls -l` against the *directory itself*., because the directory has been accessed recently enough. Run `ls -l someDirectory`, and you list all the files it contains; that's still true when the directory is `.`.

Comment: And Charles, thank you for your help, it is truly appreciated.

Comment: ...notably, when it's done listing the directory as a whole, it presumably goes on to re-list all the individual files for which the filter matches -- so you're going to see those files listed twice.

Comment: If you passed `-d` to `ls`, as I suggested above, you wouldn't have this problem, because it would list the directory as one entry, rather than emitting a line for every file the directory contains.

Answer (score 1):

Because one of the matches is the directory entry.

The *real* lesson here is to not use `ls` in scripts. `find` has excellent, unambiguous replacements like the `-printf` predicate. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

You probably also want to add `-type f` to avoid listing directories.

```
find . -type f -amin -2160 -printf '%s %f\n'
```

What you put in the format string obviously depends on which information exactly you actually want to extract for each matched file.

Comment: Hi, I think I understand: the "." is a directory object, so to speak, to Linux so it will list everything there in the absence of the -name parm.  But since it returns all 1237 files it seems it ignores the -amin parm?  Why is this?  I REALLY appreciate your time.  Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewGrady, the `-amin` isn't ignored -- `ls` is *also* called against the individual files that pass the filter, but only after it's been called against the directory itself (since the directory passes the filter, and comes first in `find`'s iteration order).

Comment: @AndrewGrady, ...one important thing to note: There's no magic in terms of communication of constraints between `find` and `ls`; `find` is running `ls` just like you would at a command line (except without a shell involved, but that's a trivial detail). Thus, when `find` runs `ls -l .`, it displays everything without regard to filters, just as it does when _you_ run `ls -l .`.

Comment: Wow that's amazing.  How did you figure all this out?  So since the current directory (".") passed the criterion of `-amin`, it executed `ls -l` against that, which happened to contain 1237 files, which is why the `-type f` is so important.  Thank you, Charles.

Answer (score 0):

The first name output by

```
find .
```

is

```
.
```

which, when sent to `ls` will list all the files in the current directory. In your first example, `.` was excluded by `-name "Ar*"` You could get the same effect by telling `find` to only emit regular-files (not directories) with

```
find . -type f …
```

Comment: This also works:  find . -type f -amin -2160 | xargs ls -l

Comment: Great.  This is perfect.  Thank you all so much.